# How to install KDE-Connect 1.0 on Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, cmake, qt5, kde-connect

I have an older version of KDE-Connect installed (version 0.8). Now that version 1.0 is released, I wanted to install it but it is not listed in muon package manager (or the default "Discover" in Kubuntu). I found this: http://download.kde.org/stable/kdeconnect/1.0/src/kdeconnect-kde-1.0.tar.xz.mirrorlist
which is same as this:
https://github.com/albertvaka/kdeconnect-kde
But there is no configure or make file. The readme does not provide any special steps required for installation. How can I install the new version? Also, could there be some reason that the latest version is not listed?

**Edit: **There is a CMakeLists.txt file but cmake gives a bunch of errors about QT5 packages config files not found.

Comment: You have to compile it to get version 1.0. Do you want to compile it?

Comment: Yes. Are there any risks involved with compiling it?

Comment: I tried compiling it. but since you weren't answering, i didn't proceed much. It seems you need qt 5.6 for it. And the problem is there are no qt 5.6 satisfying every dependencies.

Comment: Yes, there are risks. It might break existing qt and kde apps. But I'm not sure

Comment: So that means it may not even work since the dependencies won't be satisfied? Along with breaking the existing qt and KDE apps? Does not seem like a risk worth taking. Btw, when can one generally expect the 1.0 version in the official package managers?